# Running a simple command at startup in Fedora 37 using Systemd?

Tags: fedora, systemd, startup, daemon, systemd-unit

I simply want to execute a single command during startup, before any user logs in. (More precisely, I want to run a `setkeycodes` command to fix a quirk of my laptop's keyboard, so that it works correctly when a user types their username and password.)

I understand that I need to write a service as a unit file, but sould that be a *system* service or a *user* service, and where sould that unit file go? Also sould it be of type *simple* or *oneshot*? My guess, based on the documentation I've read and other questions on this site, would be a system service since `setkeycodes` requires root privileges, residing in `/etc/systemd/system/`, and of type oneshot, but like I said this is a guess.

I know that thousands of variations of this exact question must have been asked on the internet, and I really tried to understand just enough about systemd on my own to do this myself, but the Fedora documentation didn't clear things up for me, and the systemd manpages are quite overwhelming.

Comment: Originally written for Ubuntu, but should work well enough for this: https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/158442

Comment: Just to confirm: muru's link is applicable, and your guesses are entirely correct. As the `systemd.service(5)` man page says, `Type=oneshot` often works best when paired with `RemainAfterExit=yes`.

Comment: Yup, I followed muru's link and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the helpful tip! I did read that part of the man pages, but it was so above my current level of understanding that I wasn't confident I properly understood what it meant.

Comment: I would use `[Install] WantedBy=graphical.target`.  This is the target that is raised when your display manager is started.  Then run it as a `system` service since none of your users are logged in yet and you want to apply this to all users.

Comment: In case things get hairy, which display manager do you use?  It's possible that you may need to run this as the display-manager's system user.